# Using CRTP technique to ensure unique template arguments

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

From `boost::units`:

```
struct my_base_dimension1 : units::base_dimension<my_base_dimension1, 1> { };  // ok
struct my_base_dimension2 : units::base_dimension<my_base_dimension2, 2> { };  // ok
struct my_base_dimension3 : units::base_dimension<my_base_dimension3, 2> { };  // error
```

I'm trying to understand how the code ensures that template arguments are unique.  I don't understand how `check_base_dimension` ends up returning a non-zero, which triggers `ordinal_has_already_been_defined<true>`.  I think it has something to do with `boost_units_is_registered()` being redefined in `base_dimension`, but I have no idea how the `friend` version gets called.  Any ideas?

The files in question are `base_dimension.hpp` and `prevent_redefinition.hpp`.

```
template<class Derived, long N,
         class = typename detail::ordinal_has_already_been_defined<
             check_base_dimension<Derived, N>::value
             >::type
         >
class base_dimension : public ordinal<N>
{
public:
    typedef base_dimension this_type;
    typedef list<dim<Derived,static_rational<1> >, dimensionless_type> dimension_type;
    typedef Derived type;

private:                                                                                                                           
    friend Derived*
    check_double_register(const units::base_dimension_ordinal<N>&)
        { return(0); }

    friend detail::yes
    boost_units_is_registered(const units::base_dimension_ordinal<N>&)
        { detail::yes result; return(result); }

    friend detail::yes
    boost_units_is_registered(const units::base_dimension_pair<Derived, N>&)
        { detail::yes result; return(result); }
};
```

Comment: Do you know where `detail::yes` and `detail::no` are defined? I've been trying to read through the Boost source on this, but I think I'm getting just as confused as you are.

Comment: @DragoonWraith `detail::yes` and `detail::no` are in `prevent_redefinition.hpp` file.

Comment: So they are! I feel dumb for having missed them. Hmmm... well, I'll keep looking and seeing if I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I believe I have it.

The answer is in this section:

```
        /// Register this ordinal
        /// INTERNAL ONLY
        friend detail::yes 
        boost_units_is_registered(const units::base_dimension_ordinal&) 
        { return(detail::yes()); }

        /// But make sure we can identify the current instantiation!
        /// INTERNAL ONLY
        friend detail::yes 
        boost_units_is_registered(const units::base_dimension_pair&) 
        { return(detail::yes()); }
```

The `friend` declaration indicates that a function matching those arguments exists, and returns `detail::yes`.

When the `enum` in `check_base_dimension` is instantiated for a given template, it looks for a `boost_units_is_registered` function that takes those two types. If no previous instantiation of those template parameters exists, it finds the function defined in `prevent_redefinition.hpp` that returns a `detail::no`, but if one *does* exist, it finds a declaration of a function (the `friend`) matching those arguments that returns the `detail::yes`.

It's important to note that this is all at compile-time, not run-time. The compiler users [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) to find a matching function. The `sizeof` the result of that function depends only on what the function returns – it does not need to be run or called at all, it just needs a declaration that gives the return value's size. So when the compiler finds the `friend` function, it can determine the `sizeof` the return value then-and-there – the function need not actually have a definition. Of course, if you tried to use it (as in, have it actually run), you'd get a linker error, since it is declared but never defined.

As a result, the `sizeof()` is determined, at compile time, to be the size of a `detail::yes` which is distinct from the size of a `detail::no`. The result of the expression is thus `false`, and therefore `check_base_dimension::value` is `false`, and the instantiation of `ordinal_has_already_been_defined` does not get a member variable called `type`.

The compiler therefore throws an error stating that

```
detail::ordinal_has_already_been_defined<check_base_dimension<Derived, N>::value> does not have a member variable 'type'
```

Or similar. In the end, the goal is achieved: you cannot compile the code with two instances of the class with the same template parameter values. Huzzah!

Comment: sorry, but you haven't said anything that I don't already know, and I still don't know how `boost_units_is_registered` redefined in `base_dimension` is getting called.  Yes, I know it's getting called which makes the whole thing work, but how?  I haven't be able to call it (instantiate it) directly; how would you call it?

Comment: @Arlen: Ah, my apologies, that was unclear. I've updated the answer some to try to clarify. Let me know if that explains things for you.